# Why do my images saved in directory not appear after a new build is installed?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I save images from user's photo library like this

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
    let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let result = jpgImageData!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) 
    return result
}

func getDocumentsURL() -> NSURL {
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String 
    let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL.path!
}

let imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)
saveImage(yourPickedImage, path: imagePath)
```

And I read those images like this

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    return image
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell


    cell.backgroundImage.image = loadImageFromPath(String(Globals.imagesArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]))
```

This all works fine, until I install a new build in Xcode 8, the images do not load into the UIImageView.

I have a feeling it could be that the file path changes, because the images do load if I quit and restart the app, but not from a new build.

How do I remedy this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as you already suspect, is that you are saving the value of `path` and using it later to try to load the file. You can't do that, because the path will be different each time. You need to go through all the work of calling `imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)` in order to *load* the path, just as you did when you *saved* it.

(Also, though this has nothing to do with your question, constructing a URL and then making a string path out of it, as you do in `fileInDocumentsDirectory`, is silly. Stick to the URL throughout!)

Comment: Hi, thanks your help. Do I put imagePath = fileindocumentsdirectory(myimagename) in loadimagefrompath() ?

Comment: Think about your `Globals.imagesArray`. It contains the full _paths_. Instead, do what you did when you saved the file originally. Put only the image file _name_ in `Globals.imagesArray`, and when the time comes to load, _calculate_ the full URL / path just as you did when you saved.